# How to edit the expression "setosa" in the chart?

Tags: r, filter, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like to edit the word: setosa. I have tried to labs and theme, but I can not change.

```
# My code:

d <- iris

my_graph <- function(i){

d %>% filter(Species== i) %>%

ggplot(aes(x=i,y=Sepal.Length,fill=i)) + geom_boxplot() +labs(x="title", y="title") + theme (legend.position="none")  -> grafico


return(grafico)

}

for( i in unique(d$Species)){
assign(paste0('gr_',i),
my_graph(i))
}

gr_setosa
```

My graph:

[This graph is the result of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wr6P.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to remove the labels on the x-axis:

```
theme (legend.position="none",
           axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image]